# jqgrid to calculate total group cell values

Tags: jqgrid, footer, calculated-columns

In jqGrid, I want to calculate the total group cell values as below. All the examples I have seen are doing it for the main footer by calling a function after load complete. Any ideas how group totals can be calculated for the below scenario?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `summarytype: 'sum'`, but that will only provide a summary of the values in each column. So to do what you are trying to accomplish, you would need separate columns for Apples, Bananas, etc.

Comment: Yes, That's the problem. I have random items in my grid and that will clutter the grid if I use each column for an item. For ex: Item A will have Apples, Bananas  and Item B will have more values than item A.